# Как на golang получить список файлов и папок в определённой папке?

Tags: golang

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как на golang получить список файлов и папок в определённой папке?

Comment: похожий вопрос: [List directory in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14668850/4279).

Answer (score 5):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(".")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, file := range files {
        fmt.Println(file.Name(), file.IsDir())
    }
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadDir
[https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo IsDir()](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo%20IsDir()) -является ли папкой

Answer (score 1):

На Go вы можете использовать функцию `os.Readdir`, чтобы получить список файлов и папок в определенной папке. Она принимает путь к папке и возвращает слайс структур `os.FileInfo`, которые содержат информацию о файлах и папках.

Вот пример кода, который использует `os.Readdir` для получения списка файлов и папок в текущей директории:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // Открываем текущую директорию
    dir, err := os.Open(".")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer dir.Close()

    // Получаем список файлов и папок
    files, err := dir.Readdir(-1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Выводим имена файлов и папок
    for _, file := range files {
        fmt.Println(file.Name())
    }
}
```

В качестве аргумента `Readdir` можете передать число, указывающее сколько файлов и папок нужно вернуть. Если вы хотите получить все файлы и папки, передайте